# Cannot read property 'name' of null Angular2 JSON

Tags: json, angular

I got this code in AppComponent:

```
getPlanetsToView(page){
  let pageToView = page*10 + 10;

  for(var i=0; i<pageToView; i++){
  this.planetsToView.push(this.planets.planets[i]);
  }

}

ngOnInit() {
   this.http.get('app/planets.json').subscribe(res => {
    this.planets = res.json();
    console.log(this.planets);
    this.getPlanetsToView(0);
  });
```

And I have this in template:

```
{{planetsToView[0].name | json}}
```

I have got problem:
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2ZWr.png)

When I tried with {{planetsToView[0] | json }} it works but contain another properties also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be this problem:

At the time your component is initialized your JSON is not yet loaded into `this.planets` because the http.get call is asynchronous. Can you try this in your template: (Note the **?** which is added)

```
{{planetsToView[0]?.name | json}}
```

The **?** is called elivs operator and is used to safe guard against undefined references in view templates. Read more here:

Comment: When I did it I got error:
main.browser.ts:10 Error: Template parse errors:(…)

Comment: I don't know where was error but when I copied it, start work. Thank you!